# npm start not working create-react-native-app

Tags: react-native, ubuntu-16.04, create-react-native-app

The npm version is 4.6.1
Also refer the [github link](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/565)

I created a normal hello world application and tried

```
create-react-native-app HelloWorldVatsal
```

it created the app and loaded all modules etc and gave success message on the terminal

After that did as below

```
cd HelloWorldVatsal
npm start
```

---

```
HelloWorldVatsal@0.1.0 start /home/mvix-vatsal/HelloWorldVatsal
react-native-scripts start

14:52:58: Unable to start server
  See https://git.io/v5vcn for more information, either install watchman or run the following snippet:
    sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
    sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! HelloWorldVatsal@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the HelloWorldVatsal@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mvix-vatsal/.npm/_logs/2018-02-19T09_22_58_504Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the error message lines that shown below;

```
See https://git.io/v5vcn for more information, either install watchman or run the following snippet:
    sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
    sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288
```

You need to install [`watchman`](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html) or run the snippets shown in the error message.

Comment: Thanks.This resolves the issue, however, watchman is not supported now by npm and they mention it as obsolete.Is there any way to install watchman?

Answer (score 1):

Just installing `watchman` worked for me :D

my system (mac) --> OSX 10.12.3

```
brew update

brew install watchman
```

Answer (score 0):

Running following worked for me on mac:

sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=5242880

sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=524288